# magento > how to get _defaultValues:protected

Tags: magento

i use this code to get product prices from magento:

```
include_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');//getting product model
$collection = $model->getCollection(); //products collection
foreach ($collection as $product) //loop for getting products
{                  
    $model->load($product->getId());
    echo $model['price'];
}
```

so, when i use this script, for some products, the right prices is given, but for some products it is not the right price.

when i var_dump() the $model->load($product->getId()); the right price is always in here:

```
["_defaultValues:protected"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["special_price"]=>
    string(7) "32.0000"
    ["visibility"]=>
    NULL
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "399.9900"
    ["name"]=>
    string(51) "Philips Home cinema met 3D Blu-ray iPod/iPhone-dock"
  }
```

How to change to code to get this 399,99 price, instead of the '1' I get when using $model['price']?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DOCs
[Class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price.html)

```
$model->getPrice();

$model->getFinalPrice();
```

and maybe you try to run price indexer

also check if this product is grouped/configurable product so you need to use different method ( $mode->getCalculatedPrice() );

Comment: i have the same question but this doesn't solve it :/ getPrice() and getFinalPrice both give me the configurable product price instead of the simple one